# How do you find which link was clicked?

Tags: javascript

How do I get a reference to the clicked link to delete the correct row?

```
<tr>
<td>c1r1</td>
<td>c2r1</td>
<td><a href="javascript:delete_row();">delete</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>c1r2</td>
<td>c2r2</td>
<td><a href="javascript:delete_row();">delete</a></td>
</tr>

function delete_row() {
    this.parent().parent().remove();
}
```

I know I can use (in jquery)

```
$('a').click(function() {
    this.parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Or even this

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    this.parent().parent().remove();
});
```

To bind the function to dynamically created links.

But I'm looking for the way to get a reference to the clicked link without jquery. I'm using jquery *inside* the function, but that is not the point.

**Edit**
Many are suggesting to use `this` in the function as parameter, I have tried that, but it returns `window`:

```
<a href="javascript:delete_row(this);">delete</a>

function delete_row(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
}

Firebug console: Window config_maker.php
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrary to all the other answers, you cannot pass `this` in this case, because that would be referring to the `window` object and not the link.  Why?  Because you are not using an event handler.  You are using the `javascript:` protocol.  Don't use that to invoke your functions, but use an event handler instead.  Change your links to this and you'll be straight...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="delete_row(this);">delete</a>
```

This is still far from ideal, as [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is the way to go these days.  But this will at least get your code working.

Comment: +1 for the last (unobtrusive) comment which I truly wish would become an axiom in javascript context.

Comment: @Mark Yeah trust me, I cringed as I typed out `javascript:void(0);`  It's been a long time since I've done that!

Comment: Thanks! Also, I remember I saw a tutorial in the early days of jquery that messed with the `target` and somehow discovered the `a`, but I have lost it and can't find it anymore.

Comment: @Majid Yes that is possible as well, using `event.target`, but even then you will run into cross-browser issues because IE calls it `srcElement` and not target!

Comment: How do you handle the href field in unobtrusive javascript? I always use `javascript:void(0);` because `#` has a tendency to take you to the top of the page.

Comment: @Andrew Depends.  What I generally do is `<a id="whatever" href="http://enable-javascript.com/">` and then make sure to cancel the click event (by returning false in the handler or calling `preventDefault()`).  This is nice because people with Javascript disabled will be elegantly redirected to a helpful resource.  You can also use `#`, and cancel the click event to prevent it from taking you to the top of the page.

Comment: @Josh Ah-hah, I forgot about canceling events. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the  reference using `this`.

```
<a href="javascript:delete_row(this);">
```

Comment: I did try that, but it still returns `window`

Comment: Try using onclick, where I'm pretty sure this will point to the link.

Comment: @Majid Yep, `this` does refer to `window` in this case.  See my answer for an explanation and a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id='row1'><td><a rel="row1" href="javascript:delete_row('row1');">delete</a></td></tr>

<tr id='row2'><td><a rel="row2" href="javascript:delete_row(this.rel);">delete</a></td></tr>
```

...

```
function delete_row(varID) {
document.getElementById(varID).remove();
```

}

or

```
function delete_row(varID) {
$('#'+varID).remove();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this might help You

```
document.addEventListener("click", listener);
function listener(event){
     if(event.target.nodeType != 'a') return false;
     document.remove(event.target.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `this`

```
<a href="javascript:delete_row(this);">
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use `this` as parameter of the function?

```
<a href="javascript:delete_row(this);">xxx</a>
```

And in Javascript:

```
function delete_row(clickedLink) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use...

```
function delete_row(link) {
    link.parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Then call `javascript:delete_row(this);`

Answer (score -1):

just check `this` object inside handler function

use  : `this.id`